# Hard disk accessible, but I cannot transfer data

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, hard-drive-recovery

I had my external HDD (My Passport Ultra, Western Digital 1TB) connected to my windows PC and I was trying to open a photo while suddenly explorer froze.
The photo did not open, and I got the usual message "explorer does not respond" (or something similar that I can't recall). Explorer then restarted by itself, and after that my HDD is now unusable. I have it connected to another PC and:

1. Browsing of the directories inside the HDD is extremely slow, and any transfer is impossible. I tried copying just one photo, and after 15/20 minutes it did not even start.
2. from the disk manager, it says that the hard disk is healthy. It also shows how much space is allocated.
3. sometimes 1. and 2. do not happen and the disk simply does not show up on "My Computer" and on the Disk Manager.
   Nevertheless, it always appears on the Devices Manager (sometimes it says "device working correctly", sometimes it says "Error code 10" on the property tab).

I have the feeling that the files are still there and somehow they can be saved, because I can browse them most of the time (but, as 1. says, I can't transfer data) !

What is the safest and effective approach (if there is any) to try and save all the important data that I have inside (thousands of family photos and videos), preserving their order and names?

Comment: It's 2 AM where I live, so no time for the full answer. If I were you I would: 0) connect the disk directly or via another casing and cable (it may be enough to fix the problem if it's not the disk what is failing); 1) get and boot live Linux distro; 2) invoke `smartctl -a` and examine the output; 3a) use `ddrescue` to clone the disk directly to another disk with the same size or 3b) to a file on a larger disk. The behavior of `ddrescue` would give me a clue on the disk condition. These are first steps. Further fixing may kill the failing drive or corrupt data, that's why we need the clone.

Comment: What behaviour would you expect from
    smartctl -a
? Before trying that, maybe it is useful to say that I tried to use Western Digital's own diagnostic tool with no success: the analysis went on for 20 minutes and it was still at 0% (while my other working HDD completed it in 3 minutes). I am more reluctant on connecting the device again as I have read that if the reading head is broken, it may scratch the plates and make more damage.

Comment: I expect `smartctl` may indicate something in `WHEN_FAILED` column. **Have you tried (0) yet?** I guess if your disk didn't get enough power to reliably spin its moving parts or even to power the electronics, the problems could be similar to what you wrote. Do you hear it spinning up? Do you hear any unusual sounds? (clicking etc.). About "not connecting the device again": you can pay the professionals for dismantling the disk and reading your data. Any homebrew solution requires connecting the drive. Reading the data once (with `ddrescue`) and working with the clone is the right thing to do.